# Asp.Net - Using Mailto during debugging on LocalHost

Tags: asp.net, anchor, mailto

I have a line of code as follows in my Asp.Net application:

```
<a href="mailto:email_address">Click To Email</a>
```

My company has used this exact line of code (where 'email_address' is the person's email) to allow users to email people and it is working on our deployed applications on the web server.  However, when I click to send an email while I am debugging (Visual Studio 2010, LocalHost), I get the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know what is causing this error?

Comment: It's not the line of code itself - `mailto:` just invokes the default mail application. Outlook is a little unusual in that when handling mailto: links, the compose email dialogue is modal - I have no idea why. It's _possible_ that if the browser has been launched by VS and VS is running with different credentials to your own, the browser window may not have permissions to invoke outlook but I'm not sure why this would happen. As a test, try running VS as an administrator (Right-click or Shift-right-click the icon depending on where it is). This might at least narrow the possibilities

Comment: Hmmmm you're right @Basic!  If I run as admin, then the link seems to be working.  Also, when I change the browser that it debugs in, while not running as Admin, the link works.  So must be something about the default browser that VS2010 uses when debugging.

Comment: <a href="mailto:email_address" target="_blank">Click To Email</a> 
Try this if it works

Comment: Are you using authentication in your site, specifically, are you using Active Directory/Integrated Windows Auth? If so, the page takes on certain attributes (server-side) and runs as the visiting user, not as the webserver. I didn't think the same applied client-side but must admit I've never tested it. Which browser is it that's having issues? IE? And what version of office/outlook are we dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

{Not an answer but too long for a comment}

I don't know what's causing the issue specifically but it seems likely it's that the browser is running with slightly modified permissions when launched by VS and thus doesn't have the required privileges to launch Outlook.

You may be able to track down the problem by using a tool such as [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from SysInternals (Now Microsoft). Actually, I recommend you get [the entire suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) of tools as there some really handy ones.

In any case, fire up procmon and add a filter so you're only seeing activity by outlook. There will be a lot of entries but at some point, probably just before the error message is displayed, you should see some entries marked `FAILED` and some permissions details. This will at least allow you to identify what - specifically - outlook was attempting to access when it hit the permissions issue and may also allow you to identify if the credentials being used are the ones you'd expect (yours).

Comment: I ran the tool and no entries came back as FAILED.  Several entries came back as NO NAME FOUND when hitting the registry.  Otherwise they were all successes.

Comment: You may want to investigate the `No name found`s but they're not particularly unusual - quite often an app will attempt to read instead of checking if a key exists first since it's one operation not two. This does imply that there is no OS-level-security reason why it's failing (No reg/file system access problem). It sounds like there's some logical check happening inside Outlook that's failing and it's calling that a permissions failure. I'm afraid I don't know why/what it could be. You could try attaching a debugger but without the source, it would be a nightmare.